# Opening a port to only one external ip address

Tags: windows, router, windows-firewall, packets

I want my port 2255 on 192.168.1.101 to accept and send packets only from and to 74.22.22.22
What settings needs to be added on the windows firewall and my router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filewall rule will need to be created on the router.  There should already be a blanket rule to deny WAN to LAN communication aside from explicitly allowed traffic, but if there is not then create a deny all rule from WAN to LAN for port 2255.  And then create a higher priority rule to allow traffic from only 74.22.22.22 to 192.168.1.101 on port 2255.

What kind of router do you have?  I may be able to be more specific with that info.

UPDATE:  Also you will want to create LAN to WAN rules to only allow traffic on that port to 74.22.22.22 as well.  So a total of 4 rules to create specific to port 2255.  A deny all from LAN to WAN, a deny all from WAN to LAN, and then allow rules with higher priority just for traffic to and from 74.22.22.22  Make sure you specify the port as a DENY all rule will kill your internet access if it's done for all ports.

Comment: tp-link tl-wr740n
I dont need to create any rule on the windows firewall?

Comment: The windows firewall would not be able to differentiate traffic between outside hosts.  It will only see that the traffic is coming from the router.  I'm not familiar with the tplink router interface, but you should be able to set up those 2 rules on there.

Comment: In a tp-link tlwr740n router i need to add this rules where?

http://www.tp-link.com/resources/simulator/TL-WR750N_V5.0/Index.htm

Comment: OK that helps.  Under forwarding use 2255 for both ports. 192.168.1.101 for IP and the rest is fine.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like the firewall will allow you to create the set of rules to only allow the traffic to and from a specific external IP.  If this is a necessity for you you will need a more robust router.  I use primarily Dell SonicWALL's and they have been great to me.  You can ask around about other home brand routers but i can not tell you for sure if any will or won't have the capabilities to create the firewall rules you need.